# SABR Model Pricing Engine in Python QuantLib

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, quantlib, sabr

I am looking for a SABR model pricing engine in Python QuantLib setting. I do know that it exists in C++ version, but not sure if available in Python. Any suggestion/feedback with respect to Python source code will be greatly appreciated!. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation of SABR in Python? Or are you looking for [QuantLib-Python](https://www.quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml) bindings?

Comment: I am looking for QuantLib-Python bindings.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Pyhton source code. An example of using the bindings to invoke the SABR functionality in QuantLib?

Comment: Yes I am looking for QuantLib-Python bindings for invoking SABR functionality.

Comment: OK, I think there is a confusion of terms here. Just to be sure: You want to have a example Python code of using the QuantLib-Python bindings to access the SABR engine.

Comment: Yes. Correct. I have gone through https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but didn't find any class/function related to SABR

Comment: I took a quick look at the GitHub-repo: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/47e41acaf2ec8d0819dd85e2e329577bd2bb8792/Python/test/sabr.py There must be something there to use :)

Comment: I have gone through that link Bob. It also provides effective implementation of SABR model in OOP framework. Thanks Bob!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple example that might be useful. Basically finding parameters for a given section. Some of the parameters might be assumed at start instead of calibrated.

```
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

strikes = [105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]
fwd = 120.44
expiryTime = 17/365
marketVols = [0.4164, 0.408, 0.3996, 0.3913, 0.3832, 0.3754, 0.3678, 0.3604]

params = [0.1] * 4
def f(params):
    vols = np.array([
        ql.sabrVolatility(strike, fwd, expiryTime, *params)
        for strike in strikes
    ])
    return ((vols - np.array(marketVols))**2 ).mean() **.5

cons=(
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  0.99 - x[1]},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1]},    
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[3]}
)

result = minimize(f, params, constraints=cons)
new_params = result['x']

newVols = [ql.sabrVolatility(strike, fwd, expiryTime, *new_params) for strike in strikes]
plt.plot(strikes, marketVols, marker='o', label="market")
plt.plot(strikes, newVols, marker='o', label="SABR")
plt.legend();
```

[image]

Comment: It works wonders!! Thanks David!!

Comment: Very nice snippet