# How to Calibrate SABR parameters by fixing Beta(Quantlib XL/Python)

Tags: programming, quantlib, excel, sabr, sabr-model

Unable to find a good example for either Quantlib XL/Python where we can calibrate Alpha, Rho and Nu by fixing Beta. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57786/sabr-model-pricing-engine-in-python-quantlib There is a good answer in this question. To fix beta, just pass in `params` to `ql.sabrVolatility` explicitly with your choice of beta fixed.

Comment: @StackG, thanks for this, but is it possible to do on QuantlibXL?